# Conversion tracking in Magento

Tags: magento, tracking, google-ads-api, criteo

I have analytics configured in magento and i can see all clients accessing the successpage.
But not all clients accessing the succeesspage, pay the ticket.
Could you give me some extention that records the reference (adwords, Criteo, etc.) on the client page? So i can make a analize of sales made,,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

We're using this extension to track everything: http://www.anowave.com/marketplace/magento-extensions/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-ua-tracking/ and if I compare the key features with your needs it suits perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated version of the google tracking code and works on Magento 1.9

1.Go to this folder
/app/design/frontend/**YOUR-THEME***/template/checkout/

2. Open the file success.phtml
3. Scroll to the very bottom of the file, below everything and add the following.  Ensure you change the values XXX_XXX with your values.  This will send over the conversion value for each order correctly without errors.

```js
<!-- Google Code for Sale From Website Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php 
//-------------------------------------------
// START ADWORDS CONVERSION VALUE TRACKING CODE
//-------------------------------------------
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$adwords_saleamt = $order_details->subtotal; 
?>

/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = XXXX_YOUR_ID_XXX;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "XXX_YOUR_COLOR_XXX";
var google_conversion_label = "XXX_YOUR_LABEL_XXX";
var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $adwords_saleamt; ?>;
var google_conversion_currency = "XXX_YOUR_CURRENCY_XXX";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/XXX_YOUR_COVERSION_ID_XXX/?value=<?php echo $adwords_saleamt; ?>&amp;currency_code=GBP&amp;label=XXX_YOUR_LABEL_XXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```